# NGINX proxy_pass URL with parameters to another path

Tags: nginx, proxy

I tried the following config in my nginx proxy:

location /new/path {
    proxy_pass http://IP_Address:PORT/old/path.html?jh=twrtax2jlqs5t07d556lfhpfn3he0og;
   }

After that, I tested it with the following URL: domain.com/new/path

My Browser shows the new path URL but in the background it opens /old/path.html without the rest after the question mark....

Any ideas? Whats wrong?

Comment: If it's an html file, are you expecting client side javascript to process the query string?

Comment: @RichardSmith I forgot to say, there is an iframe in this html file. The query string comes from this iframe...